# How to search the results in UISearchBar?

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

I want to search the results using UISearchBar for JSON array value.

I am using following code:

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = data.filter ({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text
        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.customerareatableview.reloadData()
}
```

Error will be displayed in `NSSArray` does not have named filter. how can i fixed it

Comment: check this out ..https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Search-Bar-Guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOS Swift Searching table from an Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40547613/ios-swift-searching-table-from-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

`NSSArray does not have named filter` that means you `data` is of type `NSArray`

you should better format your `dada` as `Array` and not as `NSArray`

(how to filter an NSArray -> [How to filter NSArray in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955162/how-to-filter-nsarray-in-swift) )

you should better use in your code the new Array, String, .... and not the `NS`objects

var data: [String] = ["a","b"]

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = data.filter ({ (text) -> Bool in
        return searchText.range(of: string, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    })

[...]
```

this is a little bit wrong. when you don't get any results that means not that you are not searching. also with a typo you can get an empty result. better is:

```
if searchText.isEmpty {
    searchActive = false;
} else {
    searchActive = true;
}
```